# jquery+validation multiple dropdowns

Tags: jquery

please advise me how one can validate multiple dropdowns in a form, validation should trigger if same value is selected in different dropdowns.

here, if i select same option from both the dropdown it should trigger validation.
(i am using jquery validation engine for form validations)

```
<select name="user[role_id]">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Administrator</option>
  <option value="2">User</option>
  <option value="3">Editor</option>
</select>

<select name="user[role_id]">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="1" selected="selected">Administrator</option>
  <option value="2">User</option>
  <option value="3">Editor</option>
</select>
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way is to map the selections and look for dupes.  There are better algorithms to look for dupes (i.e. exit as soon as you detect a duplicate), but I opted to use shorter code since the cost is very low: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/vqENk/

```
function HasDupe(){
    a = $('select').map(function(i,o) {
        return $(o).val();
    });
    return (a.length != $.unique(a).length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="user[role_id]">
   <option value="0">Please select</option>
   <option value="1" selected="selected">Administrator</option>
   <option value="2">User</option>
   <option value="3">Editor</option>
</select>

<select name="user[role_id]">
   <option value="0">Please select</option>
   <option value="1" selected="selected">Administrator</option>
   <option value="2">User</option>
   <option value="3">Editor</option>
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(e){
          if ($('select[name="user[role_id1]"]').val() == $('select[name="user[role_id2]"]').val()) {
        alert('select different value');//validation msg
    }
 });
</script>
```